# Codecov doesn't recognize flags from codecov.yml config

Tags: monorepo, codecov

Recently I migrate from 3 different repos to one monorepo and setup folowing `.codecov.yml` adding `flags` option. However, Codecov seems to ignore it and keeps reporting that no flags where provided.

```
coverage:
  status:
    project: no
    patch: yes
    changes: no

comment:
  require_changes: yes

flags:
  frontend:
    paths:
      - frontend/
  backend:
    paths:
      - backend/
  mobile:
    paths:
      - mobile/
```

Any ideas what else I should add to enable them?

Answer (score 2):

The file must be named `codecov.yml`, without the leading dot.  See also [Codecov documentation](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/codecov-yaml#section-can-i-name-the-file-codecov-yml):

> Can I name the file `.codecov.yml`?
>
> **No**. Starting the file with a period can cause issues detecting and reading it. The file must be placed the root of your repository to be detected. If you want to place it elsewhere, you must pass `-y <conf file>` to the bash uploader.

Comment: This answer is no longer (year 2024, March) correct - "Yes. However, the file must still be located in the repository root, dev/, or .github/ directories" - see https://docs.codecov.com/docs/codecov-yaml#can-i-name-the-file-codecovyml